# Generate an own Ecore model editor

Tags: java, eclipse, emf, ecore

I created an EMF model and generate concrete instances of this model (MyEmf.core). I use the default "Ecore Model Editor" in Eclipse, but I was wondering if it is possible to generate an own editor since I saw it is possible to generate "editor code" too.

1. Is it possible to run an own editor?
2. How to change the default labels for attribute/class names? f.e the label for the root of my model is "Root" and I will change the label to "Abc" without changing the class name

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can run the standard editor: right-click on the `yourProject.editor` project and run as eclipse application. In the newly started eclipse instance you can create a new general project and add a new file of your type (new -> other -> search for your project name). In such way, you will get a standard tree-editor for your language.

You may also create graphical and textual editors if you like. The keywords to google for are: HUTN, ESON (both text), GMF, Epsilon EuGeNia, Graphitti (graphical).

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you [Eclipse Sirius](https://eclipse.org/sirius/). It is very easy to create graphical editors using it.